# Touchcreen on Windows 7 Embedded

Tags: touchscreen, windows-7-embedded

I have one of these MPI7001 7inch capacitive touchscreen device. This is documented in [this link here](http://www.lcdwiki.com/7inch_HDMI_Display-B).

I got it to work (display and touch) on Raspbian. However I need this to run on my windows 7 Embedded device. Display works ok but touch does not work at all.

I tried various thing and also looked for the "pen and touch" settings in the control panel. However this is not even available in windows 7 embedded.

Any help you could give me? Where to look?

Comment: This is most likely a device driver issue.  Ensure that you have the proper drivers for system devices, USB, HID, and video. If you have it working with Windows 7, look at the device drivers there for differences.  Also, ask the manufacturer for the proper WES7 drivers.  If they support the OS, they will make the drivers available.

Comment: I tried and installed several drivers but nothing that worked so far. The seller is not helpful. I contacted the email provided on the website I mentioned.